# When does the Instantiation stage of an ASP.NET page lifecycle occur? And what exactly is it?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have read this page: [Viewstate n page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms972976.aspx) and also [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations) . My questions are these:

1 - Instantiaton means that the code for the control hierarchy is CREATED, and then in Initialization stage, it's executed, right?

2 - Does the Instantiation stage which is described in the page lifecycle, occur everytime? That is, does this occur for the first time and also during postbacks??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the control hierarchy is rebuilt every single time the page loads (including postbacks).

On Postback, The controls are hydrated with values from the ViewState.